# Get the id before flushing Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way of getting the ID that doctrine will give to an entity, before persist and flushing it?

Comment: How should that ID be present **before** persisting? How did you generate it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Doctrine Best Practices](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/62):

> ### Avoid auto-generated identifiers
>
> - Your db operations will block each other
> - You are denying bulk inserts
> - You cannot make multi-request transactions
> - Your object is invalid until saved
> - Your object does not work without the DB
>
> ### Use UUIDs instead
>
> ```
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
> }
> ```

*Also Doctrine supports [`UUID`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies) generation strategy itself since version 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible when your entity is configured to have id generated with `AUTO` strategy ([doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys)). In that strategy id is generated by database using serial, auto_increment or similar function depending on what database you are using. Basically database assigns id while performing INSERT.

You can however use [other strategy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys) than `AUTO`, like for example [sequence generator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#sequence-generator). In that case you are able to know id before flush but you need to update entity with this value by yourself (`Doctrine` will not do any magic here)

Comment: I don't believe sequences are a solution to this problem, but not having a generating strategy and creating unique IDs yourself would.

Answer (score 1):

Before flushing, the ID is not even assigned. And while flushing, the ID is set based on your ID logic. If it's incremental, then you can read the last row ID for the specific table, and then add +1 with that but which is not gonna be a good workaround in any way.

However, (though your question was not about this) if you need to use the ID of an entity, and for some strange reason you can't follow the suggestions above, you can double flush (and this is also not a good practice anyway, but just a workaround).

I mean, flush, then setProperty(with getID) and flush again. For example, you have a Post entity with Title property. And for some (I don't know why) reason, you want to insert the ID with the Title given by the user. So, in that case, you could do it like the following (again, it's not a good practice, and I hope someone will show a better way here) way:

```
$entityManager->flush();

$yourEntity->setText($yourEntity->getTitle() . 'with ID: ' . $yourEntity->getId());
$entityManager->persist($yourEntity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Might help.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it is not possible. Why do you need that ? 
You can use an alternative id called *code* that you generate as a uniqid() and you can use before persisting.

Comment: Im trying to make a preview of the form in another tab, so I have to send into the url, the id that this entity will get. I thought on setting a data-id in one of the HTML tags, so I can get it on JS.